# Classifiers of machine learning for different parameters of dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Why behaviour of different classifier differ for different data?
Based on what parameters we can decide the good classifier for particular dataset?

Comment: Its not clear what you actually want, and seems way to broad for SO anyway. An example of the behavier you are talking about might clear this up.

Comment: For some dataset naive bayes gives better accuracy than SVM classifier and for other dataset SVM performs better than naive bayes.
Why is it so? What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

> For some dataset naive bayes gives better accuracy than SVM classifier
>   and for other dataset SVM performs better than naive bayes. Why is it
>   so? What is the reason?

Those are completely different classifiers. If you would have one classifier which is allways better than the other one. Why would you need the "bad one" then?

First google hit about when SVM's are not the best choice:

https://www.quora.com/For-what-kind-of-classification-problems-is-SVM-a-bad-approach

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer for this question. To understand which classifier to be used when you will need to understand the algorithm behind the classification procedure.

For instance logistic regression assumes a normal distribution of y and is generally useful when a particular parameter is not a uniquely deciding factor however combined weightage of the factors make a difference, for instance in text classification.

Decision tree on the other hand splits on the basis of parameter which gives most information. So if you have a set of parameters which is highly correlated with the label, then it makes more sense to use decision tree based classifiers.

SVM, work based on identifying adequate hyperplanes. These are generally useful when it is not possible to classify data in one plane but projecting them into higher plane classifies them easily. This is a nice tutorial on SVM https://blog.statsbot.co/support-vector-machines-tutorial-c1618e635e93

In short the only way to learn which classifier will be better in which situation is to understand how they work, and then figure out if they are best for your situation.

Another, crude way will be try every classifier and pick the best one, but i don't think you are interested in that.

Comment: Ok. Thank You for the helpful answer and SVM tutorial.